# Java Annotation VS static or global variable

Tags: java, android, annotations

I'm reviewing how Java Annotations work and realizing that it's meta data for a class. I had a few questions regarding custom annotations:

1. How are annotations any more useful then a static or global class variable?
2. Can you give a real world example where an annotation is useful?

Comment: Im An Android developer ... all this info is great .... could someone tell me a Android example where this would be useful with brief code ?

Comment: If you truly think that the SOF community gave you good answers, then it is time to Google for code with our narrowed-down search queries we provided you.

Comment: Java is a well documented language anyways, you should find your answer within minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I really don't think there's any commonality at all between "annotations", "static variables" or "global variables" - it's apples, oranges and kumquats.

2) A good example of "annotations" might be JAXWS web services:

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Frwbs_jaxwsannotations.html

  In this case, JAXWS-aware tools can recognize "@WebService" classes and "@WebMethod" methods, to parse your Java code and auto-generate the appropriate proxies, stubs, WSDLs, etc etc from it.

3) Here's a good introduction to "annotations":

> *
>   http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3556176/An-Introduction-to-Java-Annotations.htm
>
> It [annotation-based development] lets us avoid writing boilerplate
>   code under many circumstances by enabling tools to generate it from
>   annotations in the source code. This leads to a declarative
>   programming style where the programmer says what should be done and
>   tools emit the code to do it."

Answer (score 1):

**[Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)** are essentially *metadata*, i.e. they tell something about a class, method or parameter but are not part of of the code they annotate. Class variables form part of the code itself and serve a very different, but equally important, purpose, that of storing data for use in the application.

One useful example is the `@Override` annotation that tells the compiler that an method already exists in a superclass. This annotation provides compile time checking to check that the method along with its arguments are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotations in order to accomplish **Aspect Orientated Programming (AOP)**. You should try reading about *Method Interceptors*: try http://docs.jboss.org/aop/1.3/aspect-framework/examples/method-execution/methodexecution.html and http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind global variables to class elements (constructors, fields, methods, etc) and query those with reflection. 
That's one difference.
Also annotation have different grade of retention: they can be stripped out from the bytecode once 'processed' by some tool, or kept during runtime to be available with reflection.

Before annotations, people was using tools like xdoclet that was binding some meta information in the java sources from the javadoc comments; those meta information was processed to generate surrounding code (i.e. for persistence in EJBs, or to generate configuration files and other sources).

Answer (score 0):

> How are annotations any more useful then a static or global class
>   variable?

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotations#Processing:

> When Java source code is compiled, annotations can be processed by
>   compiler plug-ins called annotation processors. Processors can produce
>   informational messages or create additional Java source files or
>   resources, which in turn may be compiled and processed, and also
>   modify the annotated code itself. The Java compiler conditionally
>   stores annotation metadata in the class files if the annotation has a
>   RetentionPolicy of CLASS or RUNTIME. Later, the JVM or other programs
>   can look for the metadata to determine how to interact with the
>   program elements or change their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
How are annotations any more useful then a static or global class variable?
```

They're not evil in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, lots of tools utilizing annotation to help mapping your object onto other components. ORM map each field in the DB to your objects, etc?